# auto-size iframe cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, cross-domain

I am making a web widget using iframe and javascript and i would like to make my iframe resizable to it´s content (which is loaded from other domain).

I have done some search(inclusive here at StackOverflow) and i find a couple of topics but i couldn´t find any conclusions about this issue.

Is this possible or not?

Because atm i have to set my iframe height to the maximum height of the content which in some steps of my widget gives a big white space at the bottom which dont look very good.

Note all the interactions inside the widget iframe are done completely with ajax. (The iframe src is just one html page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/) :) Also you could use postMessage - there is a crossbrowser jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Hand-coding the postMessage stuff yourself is a walk in the park. You don't need a framework to do it for you. Here is an easy example on stackoverflow: [cross-domain iframe resizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer/6940531#6940531)