# Do cross domain iFrames cause security errors in different browsers?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

We need to host another tool inside our own website (i.e. www.OurCompany.com) in an iFrame. The tool resides on a different URL (i.e. www.TheToolSite.com).

We do not need to interact with the content of the iframe. But we do need to be able to resize the iframe to fit the content.

Will browsers give security warnings or errors in this situation?

Comment: Don't think so, so long as you do not attempt to access the iframe from the parent page

Comment: Does resizing the iframe count as accessing it?

Comment: Nope - I think that it only counts if you access the `iframe.contentDocument`, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Looks like there are ways to auto size a cross domain iframe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958642/auto-size-iframe-cross-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of months since I asked this question, so I can answer from experience:  browsers don't complain about cross domain iframes.

But, cross domain iframe resizing is difficult (though not impossible).